# JS Jquery repeating a function and toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm putting together a team page where you click a person to read more. When one person is 'active' everyone else should fade out. On my test the click is triggering multiple items to open, how would I fix this so it only opens the relevant profile? p0 should open c0, p1 opens c1, etc. And how would I fade out everything else when switching between profiles?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  $(".p" + i).click(function() {

    $(".c" + i).toggleClass("open");
    $(".person").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass('active');

  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/br321dty/2/

Comment: Is there a common class between these? Or are all of these classes unique? Also if you just close them all first you should be fine.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times on SO. Please do a search for 'jquery accordion'. You don't need to loop through a jQuery object, and you do need to use DOM traversal to select the target.

Comment: @ChrisG, answers go down there. You short-circuit the SO process when you post them as comments.

Comment: @isherwood I don't post answers to duplicates; my hope is that OP gets the help they need, then deletes the question

Comment: @ChrisG an elegant solution, thanks! One thing.. profiles don't 'close' when clicked again?

Comment: I updated the fiddle.

Comment: @isherwood my fiddle should be straightforward enough though in this case? Anyway, my primary goal is to avoid duplicates and clutter. I'd rather not post at all than answer dupes.